# Port 80, 443 and 2875 monitoring in zabbix

Tags: https, monitoring, http, port-80, port-443

Im monitoring port 443 and port 80 on zabbix With simple check and i put

1. List item

[**http,,443**] instead of [**https,,443**] is that will perform the correct monitoring for port 443??
What will happened in this case???
And a other question what if want to monitor port 2875 wich service should i used with simple check?
Please your help is highly appriciated